# How to print cell exactly at the bottom of a notebook?

Tags: notebooks

I have a notebook used as "to do list" at whose top I want place a button to add automatically, at the end of the notebook, a cell containing the current date and time, and one for the "to do" note.

I have been for a long time experimenting with code similar to this:

```
btn = Button["add note",
    Block[{},
    (* here *) SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Cell];
    CellPrint @ TextCell[DateString[], "Item", Editable->False];
    CellPrint @ TextCell["", "Text", Deletable -> False];
    ];
  ]
```

where the instruction above marked as (* here *)  has been replaced each time with

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, 5000];

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell, 5000];

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Cell];

.... and many others.
```

Nevertheless, none of them places the cell precisely at the end of the notebook and moves the cursor inside the last one. Any suggestion, please ?

Of course, under no circumstance, notes written before may be at risk of deletion !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button["add note", SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], After, Notebook];
     NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], {Cell[DateString[], "Item"], Cell["", "Text"]}]
]
```

Comment: Please, can you explain the reason why the two cells have to be wrapped inside Notebook ?

Comment: They don't, just removed it :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I will ad a backup instruction like `CopyFile[NotebookFileName[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "something with a counter"}]];` also.